# how to install plpython for postgres?

Tags: postgresql, docker, debian

I have postgres image: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres
I am trying to create the python extension with the following command:

```
create extension plpythonu
```

but it fail with the error:

```
psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql:1: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/plpythonu.control": No such file or directory
```

in my Dockerfile I try to install the package:

```
FROM postgres
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt install postgresql-plpython3-12
```

I get error:

```
Unable to locate package postgresql-plpython3-12
```

How can I extend the postgresql so that I can use python ?

Comment: What version of Debian? FYI, `create extension plpythonu` will install the Python 2 version. If you want the Python 3 version you will need to do `create extension plpython3u`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found a solution to install plpython3 into my postgres container

```
FROM postgres

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install python3 postgresql-plpython3-12
COPY pg-setup-scripts/init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

and then in the entrypoint script

```
create extension plpython3u;
```

Comment: I want to do this but in a macOS environment.  So far it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: That's a postgres extension, postgresql does not run on MacOS natively.

Comment: I was trying to do the same thing as you with a container but I thought that the OS made a difference.  Turns out that 'docker build' is done in a container so regardless of OS 'apt-get' runs fine.  So your solution works and I built an image with python3/pandas/networkx that works just fine with a db I had running with a simpler postgres image.

Comment: Be sure to align the 12 in postgresql-plpython3-12 version with your psql version.